# Hash to_json and back does not preserve hashes as keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Anyone else having this issue?

```
hash_as_key = {'one' => 1, 'two' => 2}
outer_hash = {hash_as_key => 3} 

outer_hash.keys[0].class
=> Hash

as_json = outer_hash.to_json
back_to_obj = JSON.parse(as_json)

back_to_obj.keys[0]
=> "{\"one\"=>1, \"two\"=>2}"
back_to_obj.keys[0].class
=> String
```

If you have a Hash object where a key is a hash itself, converting to JSON and reverting back to a Ruby object seems to turn the key into a String.

Comment: Solution: JSON only supports strings as keys, but we've found that the YAML parser in Ruby seems to convert back and forth okay, `YAML::load(outer_hash.to_yaml)`, though I'm not sure this is 100% safe all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [keys in JSON objects are strings](http://json.org/) and nothing else:

> An *object* is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace). Each name is followed by `:` (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by `,` (comma).
>
> [image]

So your keys will become strings as soon as your data structure is converted to JSON. Then, once your data is in JSON, the original type information for your keys will be lost.

Ruby's Hashes are a fair bit more flexible and general than JSON's objects so not every Ruby Hash can be represented in JSON. If you're targeting JSON for data storage and transfer, then you'll have to limit your data to things that JSON supports or translate your data into a structure that is JSON-compatible.

If you look at the intermediate JSON you'll see what's going on:

```
> puts outer_hash.to_json
{"{\"one\"=>1, \"two\"=>2}":3}
```

So the key is the string `'{"one"=>1, "two"=>2}'` because that's what `hash_as_key.to_s` gives you. Similarly, a numeric key will be stringified with `to_s` and lose its "numberness":

```
> {1 => 2}.to_json
=> "{\"1\":2}"
```

Comment: I understand that the JSON format can't store the additional flexibility of a Ruby Hash, but would a Ruby <=> JSON parser be expected to re-create the original Ruby object given the constraints of JSON?  Or would this lead to ambiguity -- i.e. did I intend for the key to be a hash, or just a string with a "{" in it?

Comment: @hgcrpd: You can't represent all Ruby Hashes in JSON so you're stuck with guesswork and trying to infer intent based on patterns in the data and assumptions about how `to_s` behaves. It doesn't matter what's expected when you're stuck with what's reasonably possible.